# Time difference function giving negative value

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, javascript-objects, node-modules

I am using below logic to `calculate the time difference`.

However, this is giving wrong result value when `days > 1`.
Please help simplifying the code.

I will be using the time difference logic in angular framework.

```
const startDate = new Date(form.value.startDate);
const endDate = new Date();
const dateDiff = this.calculateDateDifference(startDate, endDate);

calculateDateDifference(startDate, endDate) {
    const difference = startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime();

    const seconds = Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    const days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    console.log(days + ' days ' + hours + ' hours ' + minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds');
    if (days > 1) {
        return `${days} Days, ${hours} Hours, ${minutes} Mins`;
    } else {
        return `${hours} Hours, ${minutes} Mins`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()`

Comment: Is there a way to simply the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

> The getTime() method of Date instances returns the number of milliseconds for this date since the epoch, which is defined as the midnight at the beginning of January 1, 1970, UTC.

`startDate` should have less milliseconds since the 1970 then `endDate`,

So, the right option is:

```
const difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
```

Comment: Is there a way to simply the logic?

Comment: @meallhour you can try https://momentjs.com time and date manipulation in JS is slightly painful